# Find the probability of picking a bolt

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Okay so I found this one in a textbook I tried solving it but I don't know whether I am not able to understand the question or doing a really silly mistake here it goes:A box contains $100$ bolts and $50$ nuts. It is given that $50$% bolts and $50$% nuts are rusted. Two objects are selected from the box at random. Find the probability that both are bolts or bolts are rusted.(I am really confused about what that or means can it be a misprint?)

Comment: Maybe it is a misprint: Both are bolts or both are rusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it's a misprint.

Let's it this way:

> You have $25$ rusted bolts, $25$ clean bolts, $25$ rusted nuts, and $25$ clean nuts all shuffled in a box.  Two fall out.
>
> Find the probability that either both are bolts or both are rusted.

Let $B_2$ be the event that both are bolts, let $R_2$ be the event that bother are rusted.

Go find $\mathsf P(B_2\cup R_2)$